# Angular Material Ripple Effect is off to side of element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have added angular material to my project and set up an empty component with the html from the tabs example.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Every time I click on a tab or even if I add a button the ripple effect shows outside the element off to the side.
Here's a picture of what is happening.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAVde.jpg

Edit: Figured it out. I forgot to include the line

```
@include mat.core();
```

in my custom theme

Comment: provide stackblitz example with your issue

Comment: added an example. stackblitz seems kinda buggy with scss and angular material though